# Setting Default theme for JQuery through ThemeRoller

Tags: jquery-ui, themeroller

I am using JQuery themes in my html. ThemeRoller works correctly and applies right themes. However I want to change the default theme that it sets when Page loads. For example, I want to use the 'Start' theme when html loads.  Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "loadTheme" option like that:

```
$("#themeSwitcher").themeswitcher({
    "loadTheme": "Start"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the generated CSS and images from the ThemeRoller and reference the CSS in your page.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks suggests, you need do the following:

1. Download a new theme ([jquery theme downloader](http://jqueryui.com/download/))
2. Unzip the files and put them into your website (south-street theme gets copied to: MyWebproject\Content\themes\south-street)
3. Make a reference in your html to the css:

   `<link href="Content/themes/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`